# Add spaces between cells in an animated grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use `matshow()` to create an animated grid:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def generate_array():
    return np.random.randint(1,10, (6, 6))

def update(data):
    mat.set_data(data)
    return mat 

def generate_data():
    while True:
        yield generate_array()

fig, ax = pyplt.subplots()
mat = ax.matshow(generate_array())
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, generate_data)
pyplt.show()
```

[image: 1]

**My question:**

Is it possible to insert space between the cells for better visualization? By this I mean (for example) black areas with few pixels width between the cells.

Please note that I do not search for grid lines!

Comment: what is the difference between "black areas of a few pixel width between cells" and "black gridlines"?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to reach my goal with gridlines. But when I use "pyplt.grid" it draws lines right over the cells (and not between them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `grid()` would work, but you have to either set the extent of the image to match the gridlines, or match the gridlines to the extent of the image.

The default gridlines are placed at the integers (0,1,2...). And the default extent of imshow places the center of a cell (array element) also at that location, causing the grid to draw lines right over the centers.

Extending your example above, you can set the extent afterwards to simply match the shape of the plotted array or provide it when calling `matshow`. Then drawing the grid will look correct. If you know the shape before plotting, that's probably the easiest way to find the correct extent:

```
img = generate_array()
ys, xs = img.shape
mat = ax.matshow(img, extent=[0, xs, ys, 0])

ax.grid(color='k', lw=2, clip_on=False)
```

There might be cases where you don't know the shape, you can then retrieve it from the matshow object.

```
mat = ax.matshow(generate_array())

extent = sum(zip((0,0), mat.get_size()), ())
mat.set_extent([extent[i] for i in [0,1,3,2]])
```

The `set_extent` line basically automatically determines the extent, in this example it would be equivalent to this.

```
ax.matshow(generate_array(), extent=[0,6,0,6])
```

[image]

The alternative way would be to change the location of the gridlines:

```
ext = mat.get_extent()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(ext[0], ext[1]+1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(ext[3], ext[2]+1))

ax.grid(color='k', lw=2, clip_on=False)
```

This look like:
[image]

Note that both methods have different labeling (because of the different extent). If labels/ticks are important, setting the correct image extent is probably the most robust method.